# Disable automatic network profile creation

Tags: networking, tethering

I am trying to set opendns DNS in my system. But each time I reconnect the network manager creates a new profile named `Wired Connection 2`,`Wired Connection 3` etc. How to avoid this and always stay on the same profile? I am connecting using USB Tethering

Comment: Do you have an ethernet cable plugged in? If so, what is it used for?

Comment: No ethernet cable. I use only USB Tethering

Comment: Set the `Wired Connection` not to connect automatically, and delete the other `Wired Connect 2/3/4/etc` profiles. Let me know if that works, and I'll write a quickie answer that you can accept. Thanks.

Comment: It works. Could you explain the reason for this in your answer

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

There was no ethernet cabled plugged in, yet Network-Manager kept creating new `Wired Connection` profiles. It shouldn't have. Depending on your specific ethernet hardware characteristics, it may have thought a cable was connected, and repeatedly tried to make a connection.

We set the `Wired Connection` not to connect automatically, and deleted the other `Wired Connect 2/3/4/etc` profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I found a permanent fix for this problem:

1. Add these lines to `NetworkManager.conf

   ```
   [keyfile]

   unmanaged-devices=interface-name:enp0s26u1u4
   ```
2. In the edit connection dialogue box put just interface name as device